# Render table with Meteor Handlebars template so that rows have different colors

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

How can I render a table with a handlebars-template in such a way, that each odd row has a different color than each even row?

Is there a way to get the array index within the `{{#each}}` statement or should I set an index property in the templates helper method?

Comment: You should probably use CSS (nth-child selector + even/odd rules) for this purpose. Check this link http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html and google.

Comment: I always used JS to color the rows but this seems like a much cleaner solution. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is via `nth-child` selectors:

```
.my-table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: orange;
}

.my-table tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: orangered;
}
```

It's understood by all browsers except IE <= 8, [see here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).